# How do I upgrade from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to 2008 R2 Developer

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I just got my copy of SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition, and I'm trying to install it. I wasn't able to find any specific instructions after an exhaustive search, although there is information overload on all surrounding issues.

When I insert the cd, it runs for a good deal of time, but never runs. In windows explorer, one file is shown on the cd, "Track09.cda."

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: CDA is a [virtual audio-reated file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Audio_track) ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you have the right CD in your hand. When I pop my SQL2008 R2 Dev Edition CD in and view the contents in Windows Explorer, I see a whole bunch of files including *.MSI, *.EXE, etc. etc.

Back to your question, I would back up your database(s), then uninstall the Express version and do a clean install of the 2008 Dev edition. I've done this several times myself so I know this method will work without any issues.

Comment: Thanks... odd as it is, the CD says it's 2008r2 developer. I'll look into backup/ uninstall..